# How to mock service in service test?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I try write service test, for example, I have this ExamServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ExamServiceImpl implements ExamService {

@Autowired
private final SubjectService subjectService;
private final ScoreDAO scoreDAO;

@Autowired
public ExamServiceImpl(ScoreDAO scoreDAO) {
    this.scoreDAO = scoreDAO;
}

@Override
public ResponseModel insertScore(RequestModel request) throws IOException {
    List<TeacherModel> teacher = teacherDAO.getNameList(request);
    List<StudentModel> student = studentDAO.findStudentList(teacher.get(0).getName, request.getStudentScore);

    String nameStudent = student.get(0).getFirstName() + student.get(0).getLastName();
    SubjectModel subject = subjectService.getNameSubject(request, nameStudent);

    ScoreModel score = new ScoreModel();
    score.setStudentName(request.getStudentName);
    score.setScore(request.getStudentScore);
    score.setSubject(subject.getName);

    int result = scoreDAO.insert(score);

    return result;
    }
}
```

Sample my test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ExamServiceImplTest {

@MockBean
private ScoreDAO scoreDAO;

@Autowired
private SubjectService subjectService;

@Autowired
private ExamService examService;


@Test
void insertScoreTest() {
    SubjectModel resFromSubject = new SubjectModel();
    resFromSubject.setSubject("Math");

    TeacherModel resTeacher = new Teacher()
    resTeacher.setName("test Teacher");

    StudentModel studentData = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("firstname");
    studebt.setLastName("lastname");

    Mockito.when(teacherDAO.getNameList(new RequestModel())).thenReturn(resTeacher);
    Mockito.when(studentDAO.findStudentList(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(studentData);
    Mockito.when(subjectService.getNameSubject(Mokito.any(RequestModel.class), anyString())).thenReturn(resFromSubject);
    Mockito.when(scoreDAO.insert(Mokito.any(ScoreModel.class)).thenReturn(1);

    int resultTest = examService.insertScore(new RequestModel());
    assertSame(ex, 1);

}
```

But output resultTest is error. I try debugger, I found

1. Mock studentDAO.findStudentList() return null >> mock is not working.
2. When I close code + test teacherDAO and studentDAO for test mock subjectService >> mock subjectService is not working too. (I not sure mock service should be use @Autowired or @MorkBean)

Please, could you help write me test methods? I covered with tests more simple other services.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code doesn't comply with your description or code. This doesn't even compile. Also your mocking is wrong as `new RequestModel()` isn't the same as the second `new RequestModel()`, Mockito will use the equals method (which I assume you haven't implemented) to check for equality, those aren't. Hence it feilas. Also don't use an `@SpringBootTest` for this, write a simple unit test and make sure you can inject everything through the constructor, instead of fields. Makes your testing way easier.

Comment: add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on top of your test class and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find demo application in this blog

[https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2020/05/27/introduction-to-mockito-unit-testing-framework/][1]